# External monitor on HDMI cable freezes after screen lock

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, 23.10

When restart my laptop after logging in, my external monitor is working fine, and it used to work fine for years with this laptop, until a few days ago.

When I lock the screen and log back it, the second screen is sometimes showing black, sometimes showing a still image off what was on it before.

I've updated to ubuntu 23.10, but that didnt help.

Also upgraded my nvidia driver to 535, which also didnt help.